# lldb gives error "error: process exited with status -1 (Error 1)"

Tags: c, lldb

Debugging of a basic C program fails when using lldb

The program is: hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("Hello world\n");
return (0);
}
```

After compilation, linking and running lldb and then the run command.
An error is shown

```
$ lldb hello

(lldb) target create "hello"

Current executable set to 'hello' (x86_64).

(lldb) run

error: process exited with status -1 (Error 1)
```

Any help in this regard is much appreciated

Answer (score 16):

You need to enable developer mode on a mac before you can debug something.  Run `DevToolsSecurity -status` to display the current state.  When logging in remotely (ssh) or running under something like tmux, you may not be able to debug things because UI interaction (to approve the debug session) is required.  You may be able to run `DevToolsSecurity -enable` or `sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable`?  I'm not sure if these behaviors have changed over different macOS versions.  But in general, an auth window pops up on the screen and needs to be approved by the user before the debug session is allowed to work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. on my mac, DevToolsSecurity seems already enabled. I get the message as follow "Developer mode is already enabled."

Comment: Are you ssh'ing in to a remote system?  Is your terminal session running under something like tmux?  Or are you sitting in front of a Mac, running Terminal, and running lldb from there.  Are you using the system lldb or did you build your own?

Comment: I have written a very simple hellol.c in my own mac.
Compiled it with 'clang -g -o hello hello.c'
Running the program from terminal shell, all in the same machine.

Comment: @SudheerHebbale try sudo lldb hello

Comment: `sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable` worked for me (login over ssh)

Comment: I'm still seeing the same error, even after enabling DevToolsSecurity. (macOS 10.15.6).

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a custom lldb that didn't work, even with

```
DevToolsSecurity -enable
```

Using the one that came with XCode / from brew I don't remember, but the one at

```
 /usr/bin/lldb
```

solved it.

Answer (score -1):

Disabling SIP with `csrutil disable` worked for me.

Comment: That's a bit of an overkill. Disables other useful protection as well.